# http post request to api nativescript vue

Tags: http, vue.js, request, nativescript

Hello I need help with http post request to my server and get response with authentication.

Look on the screens on 1 I use insomnia REST API application. Using this app I got success response with premium days and id.

In second image I got response just from my nativescript vue.js app where I got false response.

There is something wrong with my code. please tell me what.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a JSON object in your request body from {N} app, on the other hand you are using `FormData` with your REST client for testing.

You must either change your API to support JSON data on request body which is generally the standard way. In case if you can't do that, then you must use the [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http) plugin to send `FormData`. It will be something like,

```
var params = [
   { name: "username", value: "test" },
   { name: "password", value: "test123" },
   { name: "uuid", value: "xxxx" }
];
var task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```